# Show image view intent with universal image loader

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to start a image viewing application after loading the images with UIL. However, when I click the imageview, it shows a blank picture and gives me an exception:

```
05-25 18:34:44.908    1299-1386/com.android.gallery E/UriImage﹕ got exception decoding bitmap
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
            at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
            at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
            at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
            at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:86)
            at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.thumbBitmap(UriImage.java:120)
            at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:173)
            at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-25 18:34:44.908    1299-1386/com.android.gallery E/UriImage﹕ got exception decoding bitmap
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
            at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
            at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
            at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
            at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:204)
            at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is my image click listener:

```
   @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(final String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        File imageFile = DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(s, imageLoader.getDiscCache());
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(imageFile),"image/*");
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
```

UIL options:

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnFail(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)//display stub image untiL image is loaded
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10))
        .build();
```